# Need a join between different rows of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named projects. It has 3 rows, task_id, start_date and end _date.
It is guaranteed that the difference between the End_Date and the Start_Date is equal to 1 day for each row in the table.

If the End_Date of the tasks are consecutive, then they are part of the same project.

I need the start and end dates of projects listed by the number of days it took to complete the project in ascending order. If there is more than one project that have the same number of completion days, then order by the start date of the project.

So far I only extracted I project with a triple join, but can not list the other projects. Any idea how to use a more general JOIN in here?

input:

```
Task_ID     Start_Date End_Date
----------- ---------- ----------
1           2015-10-01 2015-10-02
2           2015-10-02 2015-10-03
3           2015-10-03 2015-10-04
4           2015-10-13 2015-10-14
5           2015-10-14 2015-10-15
6           2015-10-28 2015-10-29
7           2015-10-30 2015-10-31
```

output:

```
start_date end_date
---------- ----------
2015-10-28 2015-10-29
2015-10-30 2015-10-31
2015-10-13 2015-10-15
2015-10-01 2015-10-04
```

my query:

```
select p3.start_date,p1.end_date
from projects p1,projects p2, projects p3
where p1.start_Date=p2.end_date and p2.start_date=p3.end_date
```

my query output:

```
start_date end_date
---------- ----------
2015-10-01 2015-10-04
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  You can solve it by identifying when the islands start -- and that can use `lag()`:

```
select min(start_date), max(end_date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_end_date = start_date then 0 else 1 end) over (order by start_date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(end_date) over (order by start_date) as prev_end_date
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp
order by min(start_date);
```

The middle subquery is calculating when an "island" starts.  This occurs when the previous end date is not the start_date on the next row.

Comment: Thanks man that worked, I'll also check gaps-and-islands problem.